# Minor edits when major edits are needed?

Tags: discussion, edits

Should one approve an edit that is minor on a post that so obviously needs MAJOR editing?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29487408/revisions) for example.

I see these frequently and it's as if the editor is trying to reach their edit quota without doing the work that truly needs to be done.

This question, and many like it, are barely readable and someone makes the effort to modify the question (temporarily blocking others from doing the same) just to remove a character here and there which ultimately does nothing for the quality of the question. In the process they completely undermine the purpose of editing questions and left a poorly written question in a poor state.

Is this behavior frowned upon or is it not considered a big deal because others can (and probably will) eventually come by and fix this?

Comment: You probably should _improve_ these kind of edits then, or reject. Anyway readability of (even a hopelessly doomed) question, counts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Polishing a turd is not in fact productive.  You're just wasting your time, and in the case of a suggested edit, several other user's time for no benefit.

Comment: From what I read of the example post, I'm not sure what someone other than the OP could do with the question to improve it seeing as how it seems too broad/opinion-based for the site. However, yes it is generally frowned upon to not fix everything *you* see in the post and are able to.

Comment: @Servy _"Polishing a turd ..."_ LOL, of course. Anyway, there sometimes are kind of _turds_ being found, not immediately qualifying themselves as such. I usually edit, to make it clearer, down-, close- vote and maybe leave a comment. But I'm not working that much on the site using the "Suggested Edits" queue at all.